# Can i capture a image without showing UI in android? if Yes Can you help me out

Tags: android

I want to capture an image from the front cam on power on of a mobile so I want to know that if I can take a image without showing UI. Please help me out. If possible send me the code.

Comment: share your code what you have done till now

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

The top level steps are:

Check if there is a camera

If there is, find the id of the one you want (front or back...). Check the `findFrontFacingCamera` routine in the code below.

Open it (camera.open API call). See `safeCameraOpen`.

Create a fake `SurfaceView` and set it for the camera. Usually this is used for the preview of the camera (again, see all the way below for the typical use), but here we just trick the `camera` as we never actually display it. This, with #5, are the key differences respect to displaying the preview...

When we want to take a `picture`, triggered on any way (somebody presses a button or touches the screen or, in my case, with a timer), call `camera.takePicture`. The arguments of the method are `callback` functions that happen along the `process` of taking the `picture`. From the documentation:

http://cell0907.blogspot.in/2014/01/android-camera-capture-without.html